# prison population by ethnicity, nationality, and year, for each country

Tags: demographics, population

I am looking for some data which will let me, for each of the world's countries, inspect the number of prisoners and a breakdown of its prison population by ethnicity and nationality as a percentage of total prison population. Sex and age would also be relevant.

If possible, I would also like this information to also be available separately for each prison, while listing prison name and number of prisoners for each such prison.

Pie charts would be nice.

(relationship to immigration and birth by ethnicity data would also be helpful and could somehow provide some insight on what has been happening and where things are going or where things will be expected to be going)

Comment: Some of this data is available at http://www.prisonstudies.org/highest-to-lowest/prison-population-total?field_region_taxonomy_tid=All though not all of it.

Comment: Interesting that the US has a much larger prison population than China despite being a much smaller country. I wouldn't have expected it.